# Spring Boot - Angular: Current request is not a multipart request

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm trying to upload a file from Angular front-end to Spring Boot back-end.

**HTML**:

```
<button type="button" (click)="fileInput.click()">
    <span>Upload</span>
    <input #fileInput type="file" (change)="onFileChange($event)" style="display: none" />
</button>

<button class="button" (click)="uploadDocumento()">Upload</button>
```

**TS**:

```
  onFileChange(event: any) {
        this.file = event.target.files[0];
    }

uploadDocumento() {
        if (this.file) {
            this.baseService.uploadfile(this.file, this.url).subscribe(resp => {});
        }
    }

  public uploadfile(file: File, url: string) {
        let formParams = new FormData();
        formParams.append('file', file);
        return this.httpClient.post(url, formParams);
    }
```

**Spring Boot**:

```
  @PostMapping("/uploadFile")
    public ResponseEntity<String> uploadFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
        LOGGER.info(file);
        return null;
    }
```

I get the error: "org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Current request is not a multipart request"

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Try again on frontend, you need transfer request down with header has more:

```
'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try to replace the header of api in backend by
this line.

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/uploadFile", 
method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
```

Comment: Adding this get the error: "Content type 'application/json' not supported"

Answer (score 0):

Resolved. My interceptor add "'Content-Type': 'application/json'" to any http request.